# VBA to set cell value based on cell's defined name

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am trying to set a cell's value to "NA" based on the name object of the cell.

**Step 1:**  Get Defined Names of cells in Labeled FHLB in worksheet named FHLBCL - this works just fine.
**Step 2**  Set the value of the Cell to "NA" based on `If Left(nm.Name, 5) = "FHLB_" Then Cell.Value="NA"`.  This is the step that is causing every cell in a named range to get the value of "NA" and I cannot figure out why.

**CODE:**

```
Sub NamedRanges()
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If Left(nm.RefersTo, 8) = "=FHLBCL!" Then
            For Each cell In [CL_AllCells]
                If Left(nm.Name, 5) = "FHLB_" Then
                    cell.Value = "NA"
                Debug.Print UCase("Cell Name") & ": " & nm.Name & " and " & UCase("Refers to Cell") & ": " & nm.RefersTo
                End If
            Next cell
        End If
    Next nm

End Sub
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You are testing the same thing each loop, the name of the range.  So you are going to get the same response each time.

Comment: The first loop `For each nm in ActiveWorkbook.Names` is to make sure the code is only looking at the name objects on the sheet FHLBCL. I imagine there is a better way to do that but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Try using `Dim cell As Variant` if if that helps

Comment: I am slightly confused as to what you want... What is `[CL_AllCells]`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout  `[Cl_AllCells]` is the named range that holds all of the cells that are going to be edited with a UserForm.  Basically all I want is any cell with a defined name that starts with "FHLB" gets a value of "NA"

Comment: I cant figure this out, so Ive decided to abandon it and just write a line of code for each cell that starts with "FHLB" and gives it a value of "NA" when the User Form loads.  Thank you all for your assistance.